# Wordpress database INSERT not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm either updating or inserting data in a table depending on whether it exists or not. The update works fine as expected, but the insert is only half working.

I `explode` the input name to help with organizing the data so it looks something like this:

```
name="relation,type,state"
```

That will produce:

```
// relation is what I use to identify the relationship between text and url
// type will either be 'text' or 'url'
// state is a two character abbreviation ex: 'ca'
$key = array('relation','type','state');
```

Then I use a foreach on the fields and have the insert:

```
if($key[1] === 'text'){
    $wpdb->insert(
        'areas_module_text',
        array(
            'text'  => $value,
            'state'  => $key[2],
            'relation' => $key[0]
        ));
}else if($key[1] === 'url'){
    $wpdb->insert(
        'areas_module_urls',
        array(
            'url'  => $value,
            'state'  => $key[2],
            'relation' => $key[0]
        ));
}
```

The first `if` is working, but the second appears to just get bypassed for some reason. The code block is almost identical to the update except for the WHERE and both work fine. It's just the second part of the INSERT that is not. Why is that?

---

Here's the full script that gets executed upon form submission:

```
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        if($key != 'update-areas-module-submit' && $value != ''){
            $key = explode(',', $key);
            $textExists = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM areas_module_text WHERE relation = '".$key[0]."' AND state = '".$key[2]."'");
            $urlExists = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM areas_module_urls WHERE relation = '".$key[0]."' AND state = '".$key[2]."'");
            if($textExists || $urlExists){
                if($key[1] === 'text'){
                    $wpdb->update(
                        'areas_module_text',
                        array(
                            'text'  => $value,
                        ), array('relation' => $key[0], 'state' => $key[2]));
                }else if($key[1] === 'url'){
                    $wpdb->update(
                        'areas_module_urls',
                        array(
                            'url'  => $value,
                        ), array('relation' => $key[0], 'state' => $key[2]));
                }
            }else{
                if($key[1] === 'text'){
                    $wpdb->insert(
                        'areas_module_text',
                        array(
                            'text'  => $value,
                            'state'  => $key[2],
                            'relation' => $key[0]
                        ));
                }else if($key[1] === 'url'){
                    $wpdb->insert(
                        'areas_module_urls',
                        array(
                            'url'  => $value,
                            'state'  => $key[2],
                            'relation' => $key[0]
                        ));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo '<div class="updated"><p>Updated successfully!</p></div>';
}
```

---

### UPDATE:

I swapped the 2 `inserts` and the `url` one still didn't work. I removed the check to see if the entries exist and the `updates` section and it worked, but I obviously can't do that because it just keeps inserting new rows every time. I also dumped the data of `$key` for each input and the data appears fine so I don't understand why it isn't working.

Hopefully somebody can explain why this is happening.

Comment: can you provide full function? just because you provided `$key = array('relation','type','state');` then wrote `$key[1] === 'text'` it's a bit hard to define, how your code is working?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan I've updated it and added a description for the `$key` variable

Comment: In the `INSERT` query for the `areas_module_urls` table, right below the `$wpdb->insert();` line, add `$wpdb->show_errors(); echo $wpdb->last_error;` and see what the error says, if any.

Comment: @SallyCJ I added it in multiple places and got no errors at all. It's as if the line that checks for the `$key` to be `'url' is returning false so it doesn't even attempt that insert.

Comment: I wonder what was the `$key`? Did you try with `var_dump( $key[1] === 'url' );`? Did you also try to `trim( $key[1] );`? And I supposed the `UPDATE` operation worked well for both the `areas_module_text` and `areas_module_urls` tables? Sorry for the many questions, but I hope they'd help you.

Comment: @SallyCJ I separated them out and it works fine. Still not sure why it wouldn't work when combined. I literally just cut and pasted the code into its own block and it worked.

Comment: I'm not sure either.. and not sure if I understand what you meant by "separated them out", but I guessed you've found a workaround.